# Partitioning list of category such that sub categories don't end up breaking between two columns

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, partitioning

I want to achieve a result something of this sort:
[image: The category is followed by sub categories. If list of sub categories is greater than what could be accommodated in the column it is shown in the second column]

I have a List collection which contains a list of categories. Categories can have variable number of sub categories.

The sub-categories should be followed by category. If list of sub categories is greater than what could be accommodated in the column it should be shown in the next column.

[image]

I tried using -webkit-column-count it divides my list into columns but breaks the sub category list between columns

Following is the view code

```
@if (Model.Categories.Count > 0)
{
<ul>
foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
{

    <li class="cat-heading">
        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { Name = category.Name })">@category.Name</a>
    </li>
    if (category.SubCategories.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var subcat in category.SubCategories)
        {
            <li class="sub-cat">
                <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { Name = subcat.Name })">@subcat.Name</a>
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
}
```

Any suggestions for achieving the desired result will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS flex box. This is only supported by new browsers such as IE10+. Beware that the flex box CSS in IE10 [is different](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ie/hh673531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

CSS for the container of the categories:

```
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: 240px
}
```

If you need to support old browsers, I think the only way is thru JavaScript.

[See this sample tested in Chrome and Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/8RL6g/)

Comment: I was hoping to get some idea with the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by 'with the loop'?

Comment: 'with the loop'- Adding some css class after a particular number of Item are iterated by the foreach loop.
But your answer works fine.